# The task 'Add New User' did not complete successfully

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, client-server

I just added a role windows server essentials experience to make a client computers backup, but suddenly I can't make user accounts. It always says that

> The task 'Add New User' did not complete successfully.

Also, I try to connect my client computers to the server, but it always says that

> The server is not available, Try connecting this computer again...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to an Active Directory being set-up on the server in question, disabling that method of adding users to the server.

Try going to the start menu and type "Active Directory Users and Computers" and that window should allow you to add additional users to the Active Directory.